# null pointer exception error when checking for null variables

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee

```
<%@page import="java.sql.*"%>
<%@page import="java.util.*"%>
<%@page import="java.lang.*"%>

<%
String fname=request.getParameter("firstname");
String lname=request.getParameter("lastname");
String bday=request.getParameter("birthday");
String user="";
user = request.getParameter("username");
String pass="";
pass = request.getParameter("password");



try {
if(user.isEmpty() && pass.isEmpty()){
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/mydb", "root", "user");

String sql = "Insert into users (firstname, lastname, username, password) values('"+fname+"', '"+lname+"', '"+user+"', '"+pass+"')";
Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();

stmt.execute(sql);

conn.close();
response.sendRedirect("profile.jsp");
}

} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
} catch (SQLException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}   
%>

<html>
<body>
<form method="post">
First Name:
<input type="text" name="firstname"/>
<br>
Last Name:
<input type = "text" name="lastname"/>
<br>
Birthdate:
Day: <select name="day">
<%
for(int x=1;x<32;x++){
%>
<option value= <% out.println(x); %> ><% out.println(x); %></option>
<%
}
%>
</select>
Month: <select name="month">
<%
for(int y=1;y<13;y++){
%>
<option value= <% out.println(y); %> ><% out.println(y); %></option>
<%
}
%>
</select>
Year: <select name="year">
<%
for(int z=1985;z<2030;z++){
%>
<option value= <% out.println(z); %> ><% out.println(z); %></option>
<%
}
%>
</select>
<br>
Username:
<input type="text" name="username"/>
<br>
Password:
<input type="password" name = "password"/>
<br>
<input type="submit" value="Register"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

i get the error:

HTTP Status 500 -

type Exception report

message

descriptionThe server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.NullPointerException
root cause

java.lang.NullPointerException

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Leaving the [Bobby Tables problem](http://xkcd.com/327/) aside, you need to `null`-check your variables before calling method on them:

```
if(user != null && !user.isEmpty() && pass != null && !pass.isEmpty()){
}
```

But before this code gets into production, you owe it to yourself to fix your [SQL injection problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Otherwise, your database is at grave risk of being wiped out by a "scriptie kid" next door. Make your SQL statement parameterized, and bind values to it, rather than embedding the values into the statement.

```
String sql = "Insert into users (firstname, lastname, username, password) values(?,?,?,?)";
// Bind values to
```

Finally, it appears that you plan to store passwords in the database. Do not do that, even in a toy database that you do not plan to deploy to the Internet. That's the worst thing that you can do to your customers, even the internal ones. Read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1054022/best-way-to-store-password-in-database) to fix this problem.

Comment: i will work on the sql injection once i get to check if a variable is null. i tried if(user != null) but it proceeds even if the user is null.

Answer (score 4):

You're not checking `user` is null. You're assuming it's not null and then checking it's empty. You need to check nullness prior to checking if it's empty.

Perhaps [Apache Commons StringUtils.isBlank()](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#isBlank%28java.lang.String%29) may be of use for conciseness/reliability ?

Comment: can you give me an example? can you also explain your answer more briefly. thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing

```
if(user.isEmpty() && pass.isEmpty()){
```

with

```
if((user != null && pass != null) && (user.isEmpty() && pass.isEmpty())) {
```

Answer (score 1):

You are assinging an empty String and then replacing it immediately with a new value from request.getParameter.   This will overwrite you initialized value, so that if the parameter is null, you will have a null value for user and pass.  Then if you call isEmpty on the null String object you will get the NullPointerException

Answer (score 0):

Try with isNullOrEmpty() is place of isEmpty()